# Solver returns nan but problem.status is optimal

Tags: python, minimize, cvxpy

**Can anyone help me to fix the solver output? What else I can try? What could be the problem; constraints?, solver?, size of the problem?**

I am using python. I try to minimize the total time for a mixed-integer problem, my selection matrix is boolean.

selection matrix size is 5733 * 88.

When I run problem.solve with GLPK_MI solver, minimized total time returned as nan.

problem.status is optimal

I set verbose equal to True but it doesn't give me the problem details. 

It provides a selection matrix that fits problem constraints but it is not optimized.

```
import cvxpy

# The variable we are solving for
selection = cvxpy.Variable(shape=(5733, 88), boolean=True)

# Column sum constraint
constraint_0 = cvxpy.sum(selection, axis=0, keepdims=True) <= [[  42.,    2.,    3.,   52.,   29.,    6.,   36.,   26.,    2.,
          41.,    1.,    3.,   39.,    8.,    1.,   11.,   17.,   32.,
           1.,    9.,   18.,    1., 1709.,  322.,  270.,   58.,  804.,
          32.,   18.,    1.,   57.,   16.,   16.,    9.,    4.,    1.,
         205.,   10.,  199.,   11.,    4.,  106.,    4.,   40.,    4.,
          51.,    2.,    4.,    1.,    2.,    2.,  114.,   26.,   32.,
          23.,    1.,   52.,   12.,   16.,    9.,    4.,    1.,   41.,
           6.,   32.,   34.,    4.,   23.,  100.,    5.,   45.,    8.,
          64.,   66.,   37.,    6.,    6.,    9.,    9.,   28.,   12.,
           8.,    1.,    9.,    1.,    9.,    4., 5733.]]


# Row sums are greater than equal to 1
constraint_1 = cvxpy.sum(selection, axis=1, keepdims=True) >= np.ones((selectionRowCount,1) )

# Row sums are less than equal to 3
constraint_2 = cvxpy.sum(selection, axis=1, keepdims=True) <= (np.ones((selectionRowCount,1) )*3)

constraints = [constraint_0, constraint_1, constraint_2]


totalCost.info()
```

class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' 
Index: 5733 entries, 00011495 to 10903683 
Data columns (total 88 columns): 
0                 5733 non-null float64 
1                 5733 non-null float64 
2                 5733 non-null float64 
3                 5733 non-null float64 
4                 5733 non-null float64 
...

87                5733 non-null float64

```
totalCost.shape
# Out[52]: (5733, 88)



totalTime = cvxpy.sum(cvxpy.multiply(totalCost, selection) )

# Solving the problem
problem = cvxpy.Problem(cvxpy.Minimize(totalTime), constraints=constraints)
problem.solve(solver=cvxpy.GLPK_MI, verbose=True, max_iters=10000, warm_start=False)

# Expected result: returns total minimized time 
print(problem.status) # returns nan, no verbose output

print(problem.status) # returns optimal

# Assigns ones in diagonal according to constraints, not optimal result
print(selection.value)
```

[[1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...                    
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]]